# How to return only needed match with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

I am trying to parse a integer from a list of uris like this:

```
uri.com/upload/123456789_abc.ext
```

I am using this pattern:

```
preg_match( "#uri\.com\/upload\/(.*?)_#is", $uri, $match );
```

Which works and returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => uri.com/upload/123456789_
    [1] => 123456789
)
```

But I was wondering if there's a way to make $match == "123456789" intead of returning an array with multiple values.

**Is it possible to do it by only modifying the pattern?**

Comment: [What do you think?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) *"If **matches** is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on. "*

Comment: You can define custom functions, if that was indeed a serious requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will always return an array, but you can change the pattern, so that it only matches what you want.

```
$uri = "uri.com/upload/123456789_abc.ext";
preg_match('#(?<=uri\.com/upload/)\d+#is', $uri, $match );
print_r($match);
```

returns

> Array ( [0] => 123456789 )

so it is still an array, but it does only contain the whole match, that is your number.

`(?<=uri\\.com/upload/)` is a lookbehind, it does not match that part, so it is not part of the result.

`\d+` is only matching digits, so the `_` is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not in php. In perl, on the other hand, you do have automatic variables, like $1, $2 that refer to the last matching regex. That is, in your example, after performing the match, $1 variable would hold the integer.

So the idea is generally ok. You would love perl.. :-)